# How to crypt patches on screen

Tags: encryption, partial, hdcp

I am wondering (out of curiosity) how to encrypt a chunk of pixels (e.g. a captcha) in a server application, such that a client cannot use any kind of pattern recognition (neural networks etc.) to decrypt the pixels but will see the correct pixels on his / her screen. I have heard of techniques such as HDCP and I am wondering if there are any libraries to implement this. So my questions are:

1. Is HDCP the droid I am looking for / are there other solutions?
2. Are there any libraries that help me to implement this (in C++, Python, Go, Java, whatever)?
3. Is it possible to use this technique for various (small) patches of the screen (not fullscreen)?
4. Maybe it is even possible to encrypt/decrypt pixel patches with transparency?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What's the relationship between "the server" and the viewer here? HDCP works due to hardware support built into the graphics processor up to the monitor. Such a thing doesn't exist across the internet.

Comment: HDCP applies to transmission of data, the point at which data is rendered is outside of its scope.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Maybe HDCP is the wrong technique for this problem. Could you suggest a different approach for well separated client and server, such that the communication has to be based on TCP (or similar techniques)?

Answer (score 1):

From your description I'm assuming you're talking about a server-client relationship across the internet here. In that case: No. Way.

In order to display anything on screen, something has to decrypt/decode the data on the client and then send it to the screen. That decryption/decoding would be happening in the browser, on the CPU/GPU, and the decoded image would then be stored in memory. From there it's available to any other process, including neural networks and whatnot.

What you would need for this is some way to send encrypted data **over the internet directly to the monitor**, where it needs to be decrypted and immediately displayed. You would also somehow need to keep the implementation detail a secret, so nobody could be building a "fake monitor" to do the decryption elsewhere and get at the data this way. That's fundamentally infeasible, and even more so given the open standards based protocols and file formats on the internet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these details. I see the problem I am facing. But how do video streams prevent users from copying movies? I suppose these guys have this problem, too?

Comment: They do. And nobody is preventing anyone from copying those things. Well, okay, they're preventing the average Joe from copying those movies. But they're not stopping anyone determined enough to work around the inconveniences.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't aware of this.  I thought that HDCP was invented to avoid exactly this kind of capturing. But I am no expert... Could you explain why HDCP exists at all?

Comment: Having said all this, there's a DRM standard for the web now, which you could look into. But, again, DRM fundamentally doesn't work, and somebody who could be setting up a neural network to do image analysis on captchas would probably also be smart enough to work around the DRM…

Comment: So, DRM does not stop users making screenshots, right?

Comment: That depends on the implementation. If the entire system (video player + OS + graphics processor) is tailored to not leak DRM'd content, that part of screenshots (taken by said system) can be blacked out. But that's not the primary source of leaks I'm talking about. DRM'd content is just data. Data that needs to be decrypted using some secret sauce. If that secret sauce becomes known, anyone can create any software that can decrypt the data. And there's simply no secure supply chain here that could keep the sauce secret. QED.